# Why are UILabel line breaks at different places on the device compared to interface builder and the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I recently ran into a few problems with several multiline UILabels that I had created in interface builder. In interface builder, each label was large enough for the text it contained. Similarly, when I ran it in the simulator each label was large enough. But when I ran it on my device, some black magic caused the line breaks to occur at different places and not all of the text was visible.

I resorted to deliberately making the offending labels too big in IB, which did the trick, but I was left curious as to what was causing the differences. Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

I was using the interface builder in Xcode 4.2 through MonoTouch. The phone is a 3GS and runs iOS 4.3.5, but my simulator seems stuck on iOS 5 (which I guess might be something to do with it).

Comment: Just a guess: it is using a different font that is not available in iOS 4 and thus will substitute it with one that is wider.

Comment: It's using the system font - perhaps this is different in the different versions of iOS?

Comment: It differs depending on device. Devices with retina displays use Helvetica Neue as the system font. Older devices fall back to Helvetica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the most likely explanation is that the different versions of iOS use a slightly different System font. Interface Builder and the iPhone simulator were probably using one font, but when I put it on my iOS 4.3.5 phone it was using another. I think it is most likely to be something to do with the OS and not the device because I have since been able to try it on an iPhone 4 which was running iOS 4.2 - the behaviour was the same as on my 3GS.

Thanks to Krumelur and Mark Adams for the comments!

Comment: You should mark the question as answered (green mark below the votes) so that other people can see, when searching, that an answer is available. It's ok on SO to answer your own answer.

Comment: Yes that's what I was intending, but you have to wait a day before marking your own response as the answer and I was away for a few days so didn't get round to it.